# Trying to change value of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the value of a button when I click on it, so what I did was I created a function in JavaScript where I call the ID of the element by getting the ID of the button and through `style.backImage` try and change it.

But it shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
```

This is the code of the button:

```
<button id="id1" style="margin: 17px;" onclick="mark()"> . </button>
```

And the JavaScript function is the following:

```
function mark(){
  document.getElementById(id1).style.backgroundImage = "url('cruz.webp')";
}
```

I've tried moving the JavaScript document from the head to body in HTML but hasn't done any good.

I know it must be really simple but I appreciate your help.

Comment: `document.getElementById(id1)` should be `document.getElementById('id1')`

Comment: You can also pass `this` in the `onclick` function - `<button id="id1" style="margin: 17px;" onclick="mark(this)"> . </button>`.  Then you can do `function mark(el){ el.style.backgroundImage = "url('cruz.webp')"; }` and avoid the cost of the lookup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your code is in the JavaScript section of your code, with the function `getElementById()`.

---

You need to change the parameter passed in `getElementById()` to be like below.

```js
document.getElementById("id1");
```

The difference is that your code doesn't have `id1` surrounded in quotes, but this answer has `"id1"` surrounded in quotes.

---

The reason your error is appearing is that the variable `id1` (which is what JavaScript thinks) isn't defined, so `getElementById()` is returning `null`, which is what the error states (shown below).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
```

When you surround `id1` with quotes, JavaScript should find the element and return an `Element`, which should stop the error from appearing and make your code work correctly.